# Average-case cost analysis of the Hiring problem.

Tags: probability

The Hiring problem is as follows:

Suppose you need to hire a new office assistant through an employment agency. The employment agency sends you the details of one candidate everyday and you have to pay a small amount of money $c_i$ to interview them. However, to hire them you need to pay a much higher cost $c_h$. You are determined to have at any time, the best possible candidate so after you interview the candidate, if he is better than the current assistant, you fire the current assistant and hire the new one. Say that there are a total of $n$ candidates and the agency picks the candidate at random. 
(Explanation referred from CLRS, 3rd edition)

Since the Hiring algorithm is randomized, we want to find the average case total hiring cost. The derivation starts by calculating the probability that the candidate $i$ is hired.  Candidate $i$ is hired when he/she is better than each of the candidates $1$ through $i-1$. Since, the candidates appear in random order, each of them is equally likely to be the best and hence the candidate $i$ has the probability $1/i$ of getting hired.

This is where I am facing issues. For candidate $i$ to be hired, he simply needs to be better than the current assistant. Why is the $ith$ candidate being compared to all the  previous $i-1$ candidates? He should be just compared to the current assistant and his probability of getting hired should be $1/2$?

Comment: It was explained in the preceding paragraph: The current assistant is the best of the previous $i-1$ candidates, so pretty good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider for example the third day, where the three possible people were A (the best), B (the middle), and C (the worst).  There are six equally probable orders in which they could have arrived

- A then B then C: On the third day you are employing A and interview C.  The current assistant A is better than candidate C so no change
- A then C then B: On the third day you are employing A and interview B.  The current assistant A is better than candidate B so no change
- B then A then C: On the third day you are employing A and interview C.  The current assistant A is better than candidate C so no change
- C then A then B: On the third day you are employing A and interview B.  The current assistant A is better than candidate B so no change
- B then C then A: On the third day you are employing B and interview A.  The current assistant B is worse than candidate A so change
- C then B then A: On the third day you are employing B and interview A.  The current assistant B is worse than candidate A so change

This makes the probability of change on the third day $\frac13$ not $\frac12$ and in general on the $n$th day the probability of change is $\frac1n$ since you only change if the $n$th candidate is better than all the previous candidates